# Cannot install packages to R after brew install

Tags: r, homebrew

I've spent about an hour trying to debug this, but I think it's best to assume I haven't tried anything except `brew install r` and `install.packages("tidycensus")` and a few other packages to check if it was `tidycensus` specifically.

Let me know if there's any information I can provide.  I recently wiped the hard drive of my fairly new Mac and started fresh.

The output of `install.packages("tidycensus")`:

```
> install.packages("tidycensus")
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.5/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘rgdal’, ‘sf’, ‘tigris’, ‘units’

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/rgdal_1.3-4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1664774 bytes (1.6 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.6 MB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/sf_0.6-3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 7973054 bytes (7.6 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 7.6 MB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/tigris_0.7.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 72980 bytes (71 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 71 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/units_0.6-0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 912393 bytes (891 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 891 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/tidycensus_0.4.6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1615516 bytes (1.5 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.5 MB

* installing *source* package ‘rgdal’ ...
** package ‘rgdal’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
configure: R_HOME: /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.5.1/lib/R
configure: CC: clang
configure: CXX: clang++
configure: C++11 support available
configure: rgdal: 1.3-4
checking for /usr/bin/svnversion... yes
configure: svn revision: 766
checking for gdal-config... no
no
configure: error: gdal-config not found or not executable.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgdal’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.5/site-library/rgdal’
* installing *source* package ‘units’ ...
** package ‘units’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
configure: units: 0.6-0
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether clang++ accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... clang++ -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... rm: conftest.dSYM: is a directory
rm: conftest.dSYM: is a directory
yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for stdbool.h that conforms to C99... no
checking for _Bool... no
checking for error_at_line... no
checking for gcc... clang
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether clang accepts -g... yes
checking for clang option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for XML_ParserCreate in -lexpat... yes
checking udunits2.h usability... no
checking udunits2.h presence... no
checking for udunits2.h... no
checking udunits2/udunits2.h usability... no
checking udunits2/udunits2.h presence... no
checking for udunits2/udunits2.h... no
checking for ut_read_xml in -ludunits2... no
configure: error: in `/private/var/folders/69/wy4n7cc10n5fg5_bc8glmms80000gn/T/RtmpPtsVPP/R.INSTALLf8694f0bf387/units':
configure: error: 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  libudunits2.so not found!

  If the udunits2 library is installed in a non-standard location, use:

    --configure-args='--with-udunits2-lib=/usr/local/lib'

  for example, if the library was not found, and/or

    --configure-args='--with-udunits2-include=/usr/include/udunits2'

  if the header was not found, replacing paths with appropriate values for your
  installation. You can alternatively use the UDUNITS2_INCLUDE and UDUNITS2_LIBS
  environment variables.

  If udunits2 is not installed, please install it.
  It is required for this package.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘units’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.5/site-library/units’
ERROR: dependency ‘units’ is not available for package ‘sf’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.5/site-library/sf’
ERROR: dependencies ‘rgdal’, ‘sf’ are not available for package ‘tigris’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.5/site-library/tigris’
ERROR: dependencies ‘sf’, ‘tigris’, ‘units’ are not available for package ‘tidycensus’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.5/site-library/tidycensus’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/69/wy4n7cc10n5fg5_bc8glmms80000gn/T/Rtmp8iit6a/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("tidycensus") :
  installation of package ‘rgdal’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("tidycensus") :
  installation of package ‘units’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("tidycensus") :
  installation of package ‘sf’ had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages("tidycensus") :
  installation of package ‘tigris’ had non-zero exit status
5: In install.packages("tidycensus") :
  installation of package ‘tidycensus’ had non-zero exit status
> install.packages('tidycensus')
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.5/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘rgdal’, ‘sf’, ‘tigris’, ‘units’

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/rgdal_1.3-4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1664774 bytes (1.6 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.6 MB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/sf_0.6-3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 7973054 bytes (7.6 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 7.6 MB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/tigris_0.7.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 72980 bytes (71 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 71 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/units_0.6-0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 912393 bytes (891 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 891 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/tidycensus_0.4.6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1615516 bytes (1.5 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.5 MB

* installing *source* package ‘rgdal’ ...
** package ‘rgdal’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
configure: R_HOME: /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.5.1/lib/R
configure: CC: clang
configure: CXX: clang++
configure: C++11 support available
configure: rgdal: 1.3-4
checking for /usr/bin/svnversion... yes
configure: svn revision: 766
checking for gdal-config... no
no
configure: error: gdal-config not found or not executable.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgdal’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.5/site-library/rgdal’
* installing *source* package ‘units’ ...
** package ‘units’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
configure: units: 0.6-0
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether clang++ accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... clang++ -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... rm: conftest.dSYM: is a directory
rm: conftest.dSYM: is a directory
yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for stdbool.h that conforms to C99... no
checking for _Bool... no
checking for error_at_line... no
checking for gcc... clang
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether clang accepts -g... yes
checking for clang option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for XML_ParserCreate in -lexpat... yes
checking udunits2.h usability... no
checking udunits2.h presence... no
checking for udunits2.h... no
checking udunits2/udunits2.h usability... no
checking udunits2/udunits2.h presence... no
checking for udunits2/udunits2.h... no
checking for ut_read_xml in -ludunits2... no
configure: error: in `/private/var/folders/69/wy4n7cc10n5fg5_bc8glmms80000gn/T/RtmpuOGf6j/R.INSTALLfdd5361d965a/units':
configure: error: 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  libudunits2.so not found!

  If the udunits2 library is installed in a non-standard location, use:

    --configure-args='--with-udunits2-lib=/usr/local/lib'

  for example, if the library was not found, and/or

    --configure-args='--with-udunits2-include=/usr/include/udunits2'

  if the header was not found, replacing paths with appropriate values for your
  installation. You can alternatively use the UDUNITS2_INCLUDE and UDUNITS2_LIBS
  environment variables.

  If udunits2 is not installed, please install it.
  It is required for this package.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘units’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.5/site-library/units’
ERROR: dependency ‘units’ is not available for package ‘sf’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.5/site-library/sf’
ERROR: dependencies ‘rgdal’, ‘sf’ are not available for package ‘tigris’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.5/site-library/tigris’
ERROR: dependencies ‘sf’, ‘tigris’, ‘units’ are not available for package ‘tidycensus’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.5/site-library/tidycensus’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/69/wy4n7cc10n5fg5_bc8glmms80000gn/T/Rtmp8iit6a/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("tidycensus") :
  installation of package ‘rgdal’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("tidycensus") :
  installation of package ‘units’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("tidycensus") :
  installation of package ‘sf’ had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages("tidycensus") :
  installation of package ‘tigris’ had non-zero exit status
5: In install.packages("tidycensus") :
  installation of package ‘tidycensus’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: You should post your solution as an "answer" instead of embedding it in the top part of your question. Then mark your solution as "accepted".  (It's OK to answer your own question!)

Comment: I second what Dan says. I've rolled back your question to the last proper state. If you've solved your own problem, the solution should be placed as an answer below. Not edited into the question itself. That way the community can vote appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I had a few stray python3 config files floating around after a non-brew install of python3.  I removed python3 and reinstalled with brew.

My recommendation to users having the same problem is to run `brew doctor`.  If you are having the same problem I was, your python3 config files will be displayed as issues, and you can [uninstall python3](https://nektony.com/how-to/uninstall-python-on-mac#uninstall%20python%201) and reinstall it with `brew install python3`.

I then had a few dependencies I had to work through, some in R, and some in brew.

@comfort eagle 's suggestion of using `install_github()` after installing and importing `devtools` was also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Worked fine for me. Possible solutions:

1. Check that you have ggplot installed via github `install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")`
2. Confirm that your R-Version is ≥ 3.3.0
3. Install package via github `install_github("walkerke/tidycensus")`
4. Check other [dependencies](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidycensus/index.html)

Comment: I cannot use `install_github()` because I cannot `install.packages('devtools')`.  `version` in R returns major version = 3, minor version = 5.1 (I assume this means I'm running version 3.5.1)